# how to find the highest value in each group for multiple groups, and output it in one table

Tags: sql

The problem that I have is can't find the highest value in each group for multiple groups, and output it in one table (and this is in SQL). the tables I have are employees, orders, order_details. Every employee report to a manager and the highest value is a sum of `(quantity * (unit_price * (1-discount)))`.

Basically I want the table to contain is the top employee by revenue.

This is the result I currently get:

```
 name_of_manager |  top_employees   | revenue_by_employee
-----------------+------------------+---------------------
 Andrew Fuller   | Margaret Peacock |              128809
 Andrew Fuller   | Janet Leverling  |              108026
 Andrew Fuller   | Nancy Davolio    |               93148
 Steven Buchanan | Robert King      |               60471
 Andrew Fuller   | Laura Callahan   |               56032
 Steven Buchanan | Michael Suyama   |               43126
 Andrew Fuller   | Steven Buchanan  |               30716
 Steven Buchanan | Anne Dodsworth   |               26310
```

And this is what I want:

```
 name_of_manager |  top_employees   | revenue_by_employee
-----------------+------------------+---------------------
 Andrew Fuller   | Margaret Peacock |              128809
 Steven Buchanan | Robert King      |               60471
```

What I try to do is first create the same table twice and in the sub query I use an exists clause to ask:

> Does there exists an employee with the same manager who has a higher total revenue.

I know there is something wrong with the sub-query but since I'm pretty new to SQL I don't exactly know what's wrong. So far my code looks like this, I know it's a mess:

```
SELECT 
   (x.first_name || ' ' || x.last_name) AS name_of_manager,
   (y.first_name || ' ' || y.last_name) AS top_employees,

   FLOOR( SUM( CASE WHEN y.employee_id = z.employee_id
   AND z.order_id = p.order_id
   THEN quantity * (unit_price * (1-discount)) END))
   AS revenue_by_employee

FROM employees AS x
INNER JOIN employees AS y
ON x.employee_id = y.reports_to
INNER JOIN orders AS z
ON y.employee_id = z.employee_id
INNER JOIN order_details AS p
ON z.order_id = p.order_id

AND z.order_date < '19980101'
AND z.order_date > '19961231'

AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT
        (x2.first_name || ' ' || x2.last_name) AS name_of_manager2,
        (y2.first_name || ' ' || y2.last_name) AS top_employees2,

        FLOOR( SUM( CASE WHEN y2.employee_id = z2.employee_id
        AND z2.order_id = p2.order_id
        THEN quantity * (unit_price * (1-discount)) END))
        AS revenue_by_employee2

    FROM employees AS x2

    INNER JOIN employees AS y2
    ON x2.employee_id = y2.reports_to
    INNER JOIN orders AS z2
    ON y2.employee_id = z2.employee_id
    INNER JOIN order_details AS p2
    ON z2.order_id = p2.order_id

    AND z2.order_date < '19980101'
    AND z2.order_date > '19961231'
    AND y.employee_id <> y2.employee_id
    GROUP BY name_of_manager2, top_employees2
    HAVING(
        FLOOR( SUM( CASE WHEN y.employee_id = z.employee_id
        AND z.order_id = p.order_id
        THEN quantity * (unit_price * (1-discount)) END))
        <
        FLOOR( SUM( CASE WHEN y2.employee_id = z2.employee_id
        AND z2.order_id = p2.order_id
        THEN quantity * (unit_price * (1-discount)) END)))
    )

GROUP BY name_of_manager, top_employees
ORDER BY revenue_by_employee DESC;
```

Comment: what's your rdbms?

Comment: Remember SQL is a language and no single company (i.e., Oracle, IBM, Microsoft) owns it. It is a misnomer to have it stand for a particular DBMS. Please tag your RDBMS.

Comment: Also, if your query returns the top employee with highest revenue per manager, how can there *exist an employee with the same manager who has a higher total revenue.*?

Comment: @PeterJohansson . . . I understand your problem and sample data.  I have no idea what the query has to do with the question.  It has several tables and filtering conditions which are not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Perhaps i should've been more explicit, this is a uni assignment as you've probably guessed and that assignment has more conditions than i listed. For example the

    AND z2.order_date < '19980101'
    AND z2.order_date > '19961231'

means that only sales made during 1997 is in the total reveenue, other things like the multiple tables is because the data needed to calculate the sum is in a seperate table (order_details) which dosen't have the foreign key employee_id. Also, all employees are in the same table (managers and just normal employees).

Comment: Currently the code does not return the top employee, right now it just calculates the total revenue of each employee and then orders them by that sum as you can see by the ORDER BY at the end. Like i said there is something wrong with the sub-query but i don't know what since i'm new to sql.

Comment: the RDBMS is psql

Comment: So it as it turns out I've solved my problem, all i needed to do was to use

    DISTINCT ON (name_of_manager)

to achieve what i wanted. However this leads to a new question. The question,

"how to find the highest value in each group for multiple groups, and output it in one table"

is it a bad question that doesn't make sense if you know sql coding?